# Generate dynamic columns based on parsed value of a column spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in spark/scala that has the following format:

```
id, payload, headers
1, {foo1:bar1}, "key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;key4=value4"
2, {foo2:bar2}, "key4=foo;key5=bar;key6=zar;"
3, {foo3:bar3}, "key1=value1"
```

And basically what I need is to output the following format:

```
id, payload, key1, key2, key3, key4, key5, key6
1, {foo1:bar1}, value1, value2, value3, value4, null, null
2, {foo2:bar2}, null, null, null, foo, bar, zar
3, {foo3:bar3}, value1, null, null, null, null, null
```

So basically getting rid of the `headers` column of the input dataframe and parse the headers each one into their own column. Different rows can have different headers.

I already have a `udf` that receives a string (the headers' value) and returns a Map[String, String] with what the new columns name and values should be for a specific headers string, but I'm struggling to find a way to make it work and achieve what I want.

Do any of you folks have any leads on how to achieve this?

I'm using scala 2.12 and spark 3.x.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need are `split`, `explode` and `pivot`.

```
val resultDf = df
  .withColumn("headers", split($"headers", ";"))
  .select($"id", $"payload", explode($"headers").as("header"))
  .withColumn("key", split($"header", "=")(0))
  .withColumn("value", split($"header", "=")(1))
  .groupBy("id", "payload").pivot("key").agg(first("value"))
```

Here is full sample code

```
object Main1 extends App {
  // init spark and sample data
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Test")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val schema = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("id", IntegerType, nullable = true),
      StructField("payload", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("headers", StringType, nullable = true)
    )
  )

  val data = Seq(
    (1, "{foo1:bar1}", "key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;key4=value4"),
    (2, "{ foo2: bar2 }", "key4=foo;key5=bar;key6=zar;"),
    (3, "{foo3:bar3}", "key1=value1")
  )

  val rows = data.map { case (id, payload, headers) =>
    Row(id, payload, headers)
  }

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows), schema)

  // solution
  val df2 = df
    .withColumn("headers", split($"headers", ";"))
    .select($"id", $"payload", explode($"headers").as("header"))
    .withColumn("key", split($"header", "=")(0))
    .withColumn("value", split($"header", "=")(1))

  df2.show()

  val pivotDf = df2.groupBy("id", "payload").pivot("key").agg(first("value"))

  pivotDf.show()
}
```